# How can i limit array size in type script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```js
const arrPassword = []
const passarrayLength = 5


function addPassword(passwd) {
  if(arrPassword.length === passarrayLength)
  {
    arrPassword.shift()
  }

  arrPassword.push(passwd)
  console.log(arrPassword.length)
  console.log(arrPassword)
}

addPassword('Pass')
addPassword('Pass2')
addPassword('Pass3')
addPassword('Pass4')
addPassword('Pass5')
addPassword('Pass6')
addPassword('Pass7')
addPassword('Pass8')
addPassword('Pass9')
addPassword('Pass10')
```

I have a few cases where I want to store objects like user password history in an Array of objects to ensure he has not used the password in the last 5 times for example. My question is can I specify an array of objects with a size of 5 and then just push new passwords to array and any object in the array above size set would be discarded ? Or do I have to do this my self where I count the objects in my Array and if it is = max size I pop the oldest one before I push the new object to array ?
Based on the research I did typescript or javascript does not have a fixed array size, I can specify a array of 3 5 objects but will need to assign all 5 and even so the push would make it 6 objects as there is no limit.
So what would be the best approach to handle this ?

I included some basic concept i cam up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i need a functionality and there happens to be no such a functionality, the first thing that i think is "what am i missing?".

In this particular case all you need to do is to take the last `passarrayLength` many items from your `arrPassword` array and reassign it to the `arrPassword` array like;

```
arrPassword = arrPassword.slice(-passarrayLength);
```

like

```
[1,2,3].slice(-5);             // <- [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].slice(-5); // <- [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: You miss the point, the question was if something like that exists. So a slice(-X) would mean it will always limit the array to x no matter what the length is  ? I wrote a function which checks before push the length and then slices 1 if its 20. slice(-X) seems to be a cleaner way if there is no drawbacks

Comment: @ALP The problem is... You can not have such a generic functionality because it can not tell from where you insert the new item and what you want to do accordingly. i.e.you can use `.unshift()`, `.splice()`, `.push()` or even `a[a.length] = x` to insert a new element. It's very undeterministic so the implementation of such a functionality is left to the programmer. In this particular case it seems logical to `.push()` a new item to your array whenever it happens and apply a `.slice(-n)` everytime before you need the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

> Can I specify an array of objects with a size of 5 and then just push new passwords to array and any object in the array above size set would be discarded?

Nope. Arrays in javascript do not have a maximum size, so there is no "built in" way to do this.

> Or do I have to do this my self where I count the objects in my Array and if it is = max size I pop the oldest one before I push the new object to array?

Yep, that's exactly right. It shouldn't be too hard to make a little class that handles this logic.